# How to deal with errors when repeatedly calling lmrob in R

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

As part of a large amount of data I'm analyzing using R, I make repeated calls to lmrob from package robustbase for a series of datasets.

```
for (i in uniq.w) {
    y <- x[x$w==i,4]
    t<-seq(length(y))
    result <- try(lmrob(y~t,na.action=na.exclude))
    if(class(result) == "try-error") next;
    output[[i]] <- result
}
```

However some data sets return errors "Error in eigen(ret, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'". Which aren't suppressed by the above error handling.

So I try something like

```
for (i in uniq.w) {
    y <- x[x$w==i,4]
    t<-seq(length(y))
    result <- suppressWarnings(tryCatch(lmrob(y~t,na.action=na.exclude),error=function(e) e))
    if(inherits(result,"error")) next
    output[[i]] <- result
}
```

This does suppress the errors and warnings. However they still seem to exist somewhere in the system. When I make a subsequent call to lmrob it doesn't work. Instead it returns the same results as from the previous call. (Of course it is quite possible there is some other issue I have overlooked).

What is the correct way to approach this situation so I can repeatedly call an R function without errors impacting subsequent batches.

Later I check the results to ensure that the solution converged and discard any results where it didn't. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't suppressed by the above error handling"? `try` should catch any error, including the one you mention.

Comment: @HongOoi You are right, but for some reason the first example still throws an error. There must be something I am overlooking. As for my other comment about the subsequent call returning the same result, well that was an error on my part elsewhere. agstudy's answer works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function that you call within a loop

```
f.lmrob <- function(i){
  y <- x[x$w==i,4]
  t<-seq(length(y))
  lmrob(y~t,na.action=na.exclude)
}
```

Then using `tryCatch`, you flag the bad inputs with a custom code for example:

```
lapply(uniq.w, function(i)
  tryCatch(f.lmrob(i), error=function(e)-1000-i))
```